# Vue3: how to avoid Vitejs to erase/replace all DOM content when mounting the app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I come from Vue 2 and I was used to have my wordpress standard html pages and use some Vue components inside them. Just passed the container to the main app `el` property, and then I could use components on the container, where I wanted to, without having all the default container's content be erased or replaced. Basically, passing a dom element to the `el` property, maked that element a Vue app, with all its contents (even without any Vue components).

With Vue 3 and createApp, it seems there's no way of doing it, since as soon as I mount the app to a container (say #app), then all the container's contents are erased or replaced with component's template (if a component is passed). Even the following, which doesn't use any component, is going to clear all the #app original contents:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

createApp({

}).mount('#app');
```

How to avoid? How to just use some spare components on a free html page? And how about SFC used the same way?

Comment: You need to be more specific than that, Vue 3 still supports [in DOM templates](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats)

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question. Basically, what is changed is that with Vue2's `el` property, you could pass an existing piece of html page and get it as a Vue app. This is not the case anymore. It seems there's no way to retain existing markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically Vue always replaces the content of the element (Vue 2 was replacing the element itself, Vue 3 replaces it's inner content - [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/mount-changes.html#mounted-application-does-not-replace-the-element))

**IF** the app/component being mounted has no `template` option or `render` function, then (and only then) Vue takes the original content of the DOM element (before it mounts) and tries to compile it into render function (that is why you need [Compiler + runtime build](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#runtime-compiler-vs-runtime-only) when using in-DOM templates)

It also means that if your page consists mostly of static HTML (from WordPress) and only "small sprinkles" of Vue, this solution is very ineffective and reason why [petit-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue) exists (I recommend reading [Comparison with standard Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#comparison-with-standard-vue)

Anyway. I'm not able to reproduce your problem...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
}).mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.9/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div>
    <h2>Hello from HTML!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what can be wrong?

1. Check browser Dev tools console for any error message - if the compilation step (of the template retrieved from DOM) fails, Vue would indeed render nothing and it would feel like "Vue erases everything after mount"
2. Beware of [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats). Browsers tend to "fix" invalid HTML before Vue reads it from the DOM - can cause [strange errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67619233/381282)
3. Be sure to use a Vue distribution which includes template compiler. Failing to do so would also lead to an error and all content erased

Comment: Mmm I'm using Vitejs: could it be the issue?

Comment: @LucaReghellin Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354652/381282)